# Convert column to rows

Tags: oracle, dynamic, pivot

The data that is the table is displayed like this:

[image]

I'm trying to convert the first column to rows

So it counts how many users that are speaking a language and using word, excel etc. 
I've tried using the pivot but I can't figure out how to use it dynamically.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT kolomtellingwaarde,
         regeltellingwaarde
  FROM   analytics_bindingresults
)
pivot
(
  count(*)
  FOR kolomtellingwaarde IN ('Nederlands', 'Frans')
)
```

[image]

This code works but it only for 2 languages. As you know there are alot of languages so it's kind of impossible to list all the languages in the IN statement. Is there a way that I can create a query that get all the languages and display them as rows('headers'). I've heard it is also possible to use DECODE but I never used that before.

Comment: AFAIK there's no easy way to do it. Here's a workaround: https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/

Comment: If I use that I get an error: [1]: ORA-00904: "PIVOT": invalid identifier. Any idea?

Comment: Pivot is a function you have to create following the instructions given on the link.

Comment: I created the table he is using and the query he is using.

Comment: [Table](http://imgur.com/jncpjqE) and [Query](http://imgur.com/vs0ZRLf)

Comment: You need to create the function: Download the sources for this article: AntonsPivoting.zip. Connected as SCOTT, first run pivotFun.sql,

Comment: @vercelli Hi, sorry for the late answer. Inside the pivot.sql you still need to define all the jobs manually so this is just a workaround for not putting all jobs inside the query?

Comment: No, pivot is defined as this: `function pivot( p_stmt in varchar2, p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)', dummy in number := 0 )
return anydataset pipelined using PivotImpl` As you see it gets a stament as input parameter. Like the sample `select * from table( pivot(  'select * from city_connections' ) )`

Comment: @vercelli Sorry for all the question. Do I need to execute the whole script or just that function?

Comment: All the script. Try it before on a development environment

Comment: Oke I will try it out on monday. Thank you for help!

Comment: I get an ORA 00900 - Invalid SQL statement on this part of the pivotfun.sql file: static function ODCITablePrepare when I try to execute the script. @vercelli